# Como colocar elementos na mesma linha?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar um texto e algumas imagens pequenas na mesma linha, e deixar todo o bloco centralizado na tela.

Já tentei usar `float:left` em tudo, e fica na mesma linha, mas aí não consigo centralizar no meio da tela.

```html
<div id="parceiros">
    <p>Nossos parceiros:</p>
    <div id="logos-parceiros">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_aws.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_veesec.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_vindi.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_namecheap.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_forward.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_azure.png">
        <img src="./imagens_body/logo_encrypt.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

A ideia era ficar na mesma linha e centralizado:

Nossos parceiros: [logo1] [logo2] [logo3] ...

Comment: Boa tarde. Onde está o código do CSS? Sua pergunta precisa de mais informações para ajudarmos. Clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/479417/edit) e coloque informações adicionais para que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois por padrão, o elemento DIV vem com o *display: block;* isso faz com que o elemento ocupe um bloco, ou seja, a linha inteira. Jogando qualquer outro conteúdo para a próxima linha.

Existem várias formas de você deixar tudo na mesma linha. Eu gosto bastante de usar o flexbox. Mas em alguns casos você pode mudar o display da DIV para *inline* ao invés de deixar como *block*.

Vou te dar uma sugestão de como eu faria. No CSS adicione:

```
#parceiros{ 

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

Caso queira ver funcionando, eu adicionei um exemplo simples no Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2htgo6q/9/

Answer (score -3):

Olá, meu querido.
Você pode usar o `display: inline-block` no css do id "logos-parceiros"